# How to create a partial balance row by row in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I ‘m trying to do a query with a partial balance, where the last column is a sum row by row:

Here a set of data **A**, **the date is DD-MM-YYYY**

```
Amount | Date       
20     | 16-01-2013
 -1     | 22-01-2013
 -2     | 22-01-2013
 -3     | 23-01-2013
-9    | 24-01-2013
```

Here a set of data **B**

```
Amount | Date       
-5     | 23-01-2013
 -4     | 23-01-2013
 9     | 23-01-2013
 3     | 24-01-2013
-3    | 24-01-2013
```

I’d like to have a result like this, let's say for the set of data A:

```
Amount | Date | Balance

-9 | 24-01-2013 | 14
-3  | 23-01-2013 | 17
-2  | 22-01-2013 | 19
-1 | 22-01-2013 | 20
20  | 16-01-2013 | 0
```

I'm using this query for both data set:

```
  SELECT
    PreAgg.tData,
    PreAgg.amount,
    @PrevBal := @PrevBal - PreAgg.amount AS Total
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            pr.tData,
            pr.amount

        FROM
            tableTest pr
        ORDER BY
            pr.tData desc
    ) AS PreAgg,
    (SELECT @PrevBal := 0.00) AS SqlVars
```

Well for the data set B it works perfect for the data set A it doesn't, and I cannot understand why!

thank a lot

**SOLUTION**

Hi at the end I managed to do it.

I use a fake counter here the query:

```
 SELECT
 reference,amount,balance
 FROM
 (
 SELECT
 @id := @id + 1 AS id,t.date as reference,t.amount,
 @balance := (@balance + t.amount) AS balance
 FROM
 tmpTable t, (SELECT @id:=0, @balance:=0, @grouping:=0) AS vars
 ORDER BY
 t.tData
 ) AS x
 ORDER BY
 x.id DESC
```

Comment: My guess is that the order by create the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Your result only makes sense if I interpret the dates as DD-MM-YYYY.  Otherwise, the dates are garbled.

Assuming the dates are stored as dates (and not strings), you want "asc" instead of "desc":

```
SELECT (@rownumIn :=amount+@rownumIn) AS Balance, date, amount
FROM table_data cross join
     (SELECT @rownumIn := 0
     ) AS counter
WHERE some constraits
ORDER BY date asc;
```

I suspect you have committed the sin of storing dates as strings, though.  If this is the case, it is easily fixed using `str_to_date()`:

```
SELECT (@rownumIn :=amount+@rownumIn) AS Balance, date, amount
FROM table_data cross join
     (SELECT @rownumIn := 0
     ) AS counter
WHERE some constraits
ORDER BY str_to_date(date, '%d-%m-%Y') asc;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for you reply. I modify the text of my question. the date are in DD-MM-YYYY but still I have weird results

Comment: no unfortunately it doesn't work. My guess is that the calculation is done before the order, and this create the mess up

Comment: @NiBE . . . The calculation for `balance` is done after the `order by`.  My guess is that `date` is in a format that doesn't get converted, so no order by is taking place.

Comment: I change a bit the initial question, now is complete with data and with the query I use at the moment, thanks for your help