# Subquery with order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a query with a subquery and both of them have an order by. 
I have a weird behavior, sometimes I don't get back all the rows, sometimes I have 0 rows, but if I run the inner query I have the correct rows always. Is there some limitation about subquery?  MySql is version 5.5

thanks a lot

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        @fakeId := @fakeId + 1 AS fakeId,
        @balance := (@balance +  traIn.amount) AS balance,

    FROM
        (SELECT @fakeId := 0, @balance := 0) AS vars,
        table1 traIn
    INNER JOIN table2 traTypeIn ON traIn._id = traTypeIn.id
    INNER JOIN table3 ptfIn ON traIn.ptf_id = ptfIn.id
    LEFT JOIN `user` u ON u.id = traIn.user_create_id
    LEFT JOIN `user` up ON up.id = traIn.user_update_id

    WHERE
    <---  a couple of constraints -->
    ORDER BY
        traIn.date
) AS data
    ORDER BY data.fakeId DESC
    LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Nothing in the outer query would change the number of rows (except for the `limit` clause, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you don't, on your sub-query, select traIn.date, and after that, select only fakeId, balance
Somethings like that :

```
SELECT
data.fakeId, data.balance
FROM
(
    SELECT
        @fakeId := @fakeId + 1 AS fakeId,
        @balance := (@balance +  traIn.amount) AS balance,
        traIn.date as date1
    FROM
        (SELECT @fakeId := 0, @balance := 0) AS vars,
        table1 traIn
    INNER JOIN table2 traTypeIn ON traIn._id = traTypeIn.id
    INNER JOIN table3 ptfIn ON traIn.ptf_id = ptfIn.id
    LEFT JOIN `user` u ON u.id = traIn.user_create_id
    LEFT JOIN `user` up ON up.id = traIn.user_update_id

    WHERE
    <---  a couple of constraints -->
) AS data
    ORDER BY data.date1, data.fakeId DESC
    LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your reply. I need to have a balance in the row that change every rows and to have a correct calculation I have to order byDate1 in the subquery

Comment: Could you please show an example of what do you have on each sub-query row ?

Comment: The first problem rises with the balace, check this out for the data I'm speaking about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286834/how-to-create-a-partial-balance-row-by-row-in-sql then I fixed it with the "fakeID" but when I try with a lot of data, not the few one in the example it did not work.